# How to solve for y in formula (y*known_number)%145 = 81 without a loop

Tags: python, math, modulo

Is it possible to solve for y in this equation without a loop?

```
known_number = 7
(y * known_number) % 145 == 81
```

I'm using a loop, but i'm thinking since it's simple multiplication, there may be a formula that can be used to solve it without a loop, or is there?

Here is my code i use to solve for it:

```
known_number = 7
for y in range(145):
   if (y * known_number) % 145 == 81:
       print(y)  # -> 53
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an other way, though it has a different kind of loop if you look closely.. anyway, it can be solved like this:

```
y*known_number ≡ 81 (mod 145)
y ≡ 81 * known_number ^ -1 (mod 145)
```

Which works iff `known_number` indeed *has* a [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) modulo 145, which happens when the GCD between the known number and the modulus is 1 (`gcd(7, 145) = 1` so in this case it would work). Here the inverse is 83, so we compute `y = 81 * 83 % 145 = 53`.

In general you may find that inverse by using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, but also through various other methods, for example `pow(known_number, 111, 145)`, where 111 is `totient(145) - 1`. Computing a totient is not easy unless you have the prime-factorization of the number. The `pow` function hides a loop, but a much shorter loop than brute-forcing the equation.

Comment: Thank you, this helps, i'll be back asking other questions related to this soon, thank you so much.

Comment: FWIW, in Python 3.8 and later you can just use `pow(known_number, -1, 145)`.